# Why is my Python haversine distance calculation wrong compared to online tools and Google Maps?

Tags: python, haversine

I am writing a haversine distance and angle calculator in Python as part of a small autonomous RC car project. My two test locations are `38.63594444444444,-90.2315` and `38.63594444444444,-90.23211111111111`.

Most online calculators (and my own personal TI-89) are getting a distance of roughly 0.05308 km. However, my Python function is getting a distance of 0.06795 km. That's ~15m off and that is huge with a small RC car.

My bearing calculation function, `points2angle`, was failing until I did some float casting in my `toDegrees` function. Integer division was screwing me over.

Be warned, my `points2angle` and `points2distance` functions expect a tuple of (degrees, minutes, seconds). The two test locations are  `(38, 38, 9.4), (-90, 13, 53.4)` and `(38, 38, 9.4), (-90, 13, 55.6)` in that format.

**EDIT:** Thank you to MSeifert. I just had my latitude and longitude mixed up. I fixed my `points2angle` code below but left the error in my `points2distance` code so the difference between my wrong code and the answer was still clear.

My distance calculation (wrong distance returned):

```
  def points2distance(start,  end):  
      start_long = math.radians(toDegrees(start[0]))  
      start_latt = math.radians(toDegrees(start[1]))  
      end_long = math.radians(toDegrees(end[0]))  
      end_latt = math.radians(toDegrees(end[1]))
      d_latt = float(end_latt - start_latt)
      d_long = float(end_long - start_long)  
      a = (math.sin(d_latt/2)**2) + math.cos(start_latt) * math.cos(end_latt)* (math.sin(d_long/2)**2)  
      c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
      return 6371 * c
```

My decimal degrees conversion function (working):

```
def toDegrees(coord):
    degrees = float(math.fabs(coord[0])) + float(coord[1]/60) + float(coord[2]/3600)
    if coord[0] < 0:
        degrees = degrees*-1
    return degrees
```

My bearing angle calculation (working):

```
def points2angle(start, end):
  start_long = math.radians(toDegrees(start[1]))  
  start_latt = math.radians(toDegrees(start[0]))  
  end_long = math.radians(toDegrees(end[1]))  
  end_latt = math.radians(toDegrees(end[0]))
  d_latt = end_latt - start_latt
  d_long = end_long - start_long
  y = math.sin(d_long)*math.sin(end_latt)
  x = (math.cos(start_latt)*math.sin(end_latt)) - (math.sin(start_latt)*math.cos(end_latt)*math.cos(d_long))
  brng = math.degrees(math.atan2(y,x))
  compBear = (brng+360) % 360;
  return compBear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your longitude and latitude are mixed up, just swap them (or if they were swapped in the arguments then swap them there) and it works:

```
def points2distance(start,  end):  
    start_long = math.radians(toDegrees(start[1]))  
    start_latt = math.radians(toDegrees(start[0]))  
    end_long = math.radians(toDegrees(end[1]))  
    end_latt = math.radians(toDegrees(end[0]))
    d_latt = float(end_latt - start_latt)
    d_long = float(end_long - start_long)  
    a = (math.sin(d_latt/2)**2) + math.cos(start_latt) * math.cos(end_latt)* (math.sin(d_long/2)**2)  
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    return 6371 * c 

points2distance([(38, 38, 9.4), (-90, 13, 53.4)], [(38, 38, 9.4), (-90, 13, 55.6)])
# returns: 0.053079628495340196
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I have now broken my `points2angle` calculation, however, as I want to be sure I have that mix-up fixed everywhere. Will update when I fix that. Thank you! **Update:** Fixed the `points2angle` calculation in my question.

Comment: So everything is working or are there still discrepancies? I'm glad I could help you this far. :)

Comment: yup, everything is working and I really appreciate it. Sometimes it takes that extra set of eyes! I made sure I updated my `points2angle` code to the newly-working code in the initial post. Turns out I mistakenly switched all the variables in that code as well. However, all is fixed now. I wish I could vote on your post but I don't have enough rep.